# Error when trying to cascade pulldowns using jQuery JSON MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: items
this is the pulldown helper that triggers the error:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.OrigSampID, new SelectList(Model.OrigSampID,"OrigSampID","SampDate"))
```

this is the .change call that is supposed to make a Json call to fill the pulldown:

```
//Hook onto the SampType list's onchange event  
$("#SampType").change(function() {   

    $.getJSON('Home/GetOriginalIDs', {thisPWS: $("#PWS").val() }, function (data) {  
      //Clear the Model list    
      $("#OrigSampID").empty();    
      //Foreach Model in the list, add a model option from the data returned    
      $.each(data, function(index, optionData) {       
         $("OrigSampID").append("<option value=" + optionData.OrigSampID + ">" + optionData.SampDate + "</option>");    
      });
   });  
}).change();
```

This is the function called in the controller:

```
public JsonResult GetOriginalIDs(string thisPWS)
{

    JsonResult result = new JsonResult();

    var positives = (from c in _db.DWS_BactiBucket.OrderByDescending(x => x.SampDate)
               where c.PWS == thisPWS && c.SampType == "R" && c.IsTOTPresent == "1"
               select c).Take(6);

    result.Data = positives.ToList();
    result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
    return result;


}
```

I have tried for the last 7 hours to get a 2nd pulldown filled with data depending on what it was sent. MVC is not a tool, it's an IQ test and I am a dummy.
It would be nice to return anything from the JSON call.

Edit:
Here is the block of code in the HomeController that works to fill a pulldown at Form load time, which is not what I want, but shows the query and hooking to a pulldown works. I just can't get it to work for jQuery Ajax or Json

```
    //private List<SelectListItem> GetXX(string thisPWS)
    //{
    //    List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();

    //    var cat = (from c in _db.DWS_BactiBucket.OrderByDescending(x => x.SampDate) 
    //               where  c.PWS == thisPWS && c.SampType  == "R" && c.IsTOTPresent  == "1" select c).Take(6).ToArray();

    //    for (int i = 0; i < cat.Length; i++)
    //    {
    //        list.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = cat[i].LabSampID + " (" + cat[i].SampDate + ")", Value = cat[i].LabSampID.ToString() });
    //    }

    //    return list;
    //}
```

And here is the pulldown built to work and get loaded on form load:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.OrigSampID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Originals)
```

Comment: The exception is occurring in your controller. Is the value of `thisPWS` valid? Is the query returning a valid collection?

Comment: I put breakpoint in the controller Get first time through for the Add View and it made it there, it went on to load the View, and I stepped through all the inputs until I got to the 2nd Pullddown where I got the error. It never got to change event of 1st pulldown, or json of 1st pulldown. So it is wanting something when the form loads. This might be understandable because I don't fill 2nd pulldown until 1st pulldown gets run. Not sure if my syntax is correct or how to check for is null in razor.
As far as your second question, it never gets to the query that returns a valid list.

Comment: I can see one problem in your `@Html.Dropdown()` method - your are binding to property `model.OrigSampID` but then creating a select list based on `Model.OrigSampID` which makes no sense. `OrigSampID` must be a primitive value (e.g. `int` or `string`) if that what you binding to but `SelectList` takes a collection as its first parameter. There may be other problems but cant tell without seeing more code. You should include your model and the GET method for displaying the initial view.

Comment: So what do I bind the @Html.Dropdown() to?
I believe that you are correct?
The Controller is returning a list (that is the last block of code in my question). The query works if I was to fill a pulldown on load with an IEnumerable collection.
I'm not sure how to reference this list in the jQuery GetJson (which is my second block of code above). The Model is EF and it does have a table with the columns I am referencing, OrigSampID, SampDate, SampType, and PWS. 
I can't seem to reference the collection/list/whatever the controller returns.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want without seeing more code but if you want an empty dropdown on initial load then use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OrigSampID, new SelectList(IEnumerable.Empty<T>))` You can also improve your JSON by returning a collection of anonymous object containing only the value and text properties necessary for the options (less payload sent to the browser) - `..select new { ID = c.OrigSampID, Name = c.SampDate }...`

Answer (score 0):

I worked with our team lead who was in the office today and came up with this solution:

**helper:**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.OrigSampID, new List<SelectListItem>())
```

**change event to start everything:**

```
$("#SampType").change(function () {

    if ($(this).val() == "P") {
        retrieveDropDown($("#PWS").val());
    }
});

function retrieveDropDown(thisPWS) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/GetDropDownList/" + thisPWS,
        type: 'POST',
        success: handleResultResponse,
        error: function (xhr) { alert("Error..."); }
    });
}
```

**in controller, Json action to get items:**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetDropDownList(string id)
{
    var positives = (from c in _db.DWS_BactiBucket.OrderByDescending(x => x.SampDate)
                     where c.PWS == id && c.SampType == "R" && c.IsTOTPresent == "1"
                     select c).Take(6).ToList();

    var results = new JsonResult();

    if (positives.Any())
    {
        var listItems = positives.Select(p => new SelectListItem{
           Selected = false,
           Text = p.LabSampID.ToString() + ":::" + p.SampDate.Value.ToShortDateString(),
           Value = p.LabSampID.ToString()
        }).ToList();

        results = new JsonResult { Data = listItems };
    }


    return results;
}
```

**back in view loading pulldwon with what comes back:**

```
//handles data back from ajax call
function handleResultResponse(responseObject) {
    populateDropDown("OrigSampID", responseObject);

}

//populates the drop down from the json object (list<selectlistitem>)
function populateDropDown(dropdownId, jsonObject) {
    //remove all items from list
    $('#' + dropdownId).find('option').remove();

    //add the options in for this list
    $.each(jsonObject, function () {
        $('#' + dropdownId)
     .append($('<option>', { value: this.Value })
     .text(this.Text));
    });
}
```